# Issue with running JAR from Desktop, but not from command line or Eclipse

Tags: java, concurrency, jar, io, swingworker

I am running into a peculiar issue (peculiar for me anyways) that seems to happen in a `SwingWorker` that I use for saving the result of another 'SwingWorker' thread as a tab-delimited file (just a spreadsheet of data).

Here is the worker, that initializes and declares an object which organizes the data and writes each table row to a file (using `BufferedWriter`):

```
// Some instance variables outside of the SwingWorker:
// model: holds a matrix of numerical data (double[][])
// view: the GUI class

class SaveWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

        /* The finished reordered matrix axes */
        private String[] reorderedRows;
        private String[] reorderedCols;
        private String filePath;  // the path of the file that will be generated

        public SaveWorker(String[] reorderedRows, String[] reorderedCols) {

            // variables have been checked for null outside of the worker
            this.reorderedRows = reorderedRows;
            this.reorderedCols = reorderedCols;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

            if (!isCancelled()) {
                LogBuffer.println("Initializing writer.");
                final CDTGenerator cdtGen = new CDTGenerator(
                        model, view, reorderedRows, reorderedCols);

                LogBuffer.println("Generating CDT.");
                cdtGen.generateCDT();

                LogBuffer.println("Setting file path.");
                filePath = cdtGen.getFilePath();         // stops inside here, jumps to done()
                LogBuffer.println("Path: " + filePath);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {

            if (!isCancelled()) {
                view.setLoadText("Done!");
                LogBuffer.println("Done saving. Opening file now.");

                // need filePath here to load and then display generated file
                visualizeData(filePath);

            } else {
                view.setReorderOngoing(false);
                LogBuffer.println("Reordering has been cancelled.");
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run the program from Eclipse, this all works perfectly fine. No issues whatsoever. Now I know there have been tons of question on here that are about Eclipse running fine while the runnable JAR fails. It's often due to not including dependencies or referring to them in the wrong way. But what's weird is that the JAR *also* works completely fine when it's being started from command line (Windows 8.1):

```
java -jar reorder.jar
```

Et voilà, everything as expected. The `CDTGenerator` will finish, write all the matrix rows to a file, and return the `filePath`. With the `filePath` I can subsequently open the new file and display the matrix.

In the case of double-clicking the JAR on my desktop, where I placed it when creating it from Eclipse, this is where the program will let me know that stuff happens. I get the error message I created for the case of `filePath == null` and using some logging I closed in on where the `CDTGenerator` object stops executing its method `generateCDT()` (Eclipse debugger *also* won't reproduce the error and do everything as planned).

What the log shows made me think it's an issue with concurrency, but I am actually leaning against that because Eclipse *and* command line both run the code fine. The log just tells me that the code suddenly stops executing during a loop which transforms `double` values from a matrix row (`double[]`) to `Strings` to be stored in a `String[]` for later writing with `BufferedWriter`.

If I use more logging in that loop, the loop will stop at a different iterator (???).

Furthermore, the code *does* work for small matrices (130x130) but not for larger ones (1500x3500) but I haven't tested where the limit is. This makes it seem almost time dependent, or memory.

I also used jVisualVM to look at potential memory issues, but even for the larger matrices I am on ~250MB which is nowhere near problematic regarding potential `OutOfMemoryExceptions`.

And finally, the last potential factor I can think of: Generating the JAR 'fails' due to some `classpath` issues (clean & rebuild have no effect...) but this has never been an issue before as I have run the code many many times using the 'broken' JAR and execute from Desktop.

I am a real newbie to programming, so please point in some direction if possible. I have tried to find logged exceptions, logged the values of variables, I am checking for `null` and `IndexOutOfBound` issues at the array where it stops executing... I am at a complete loss *especially* because this runs fine from command line.

Comment: Please, could you post the stack trace of your error?  If you have any problem at visualizing it, try configuring some logger in order to dump it into a file, but the full trace would be very useful

Comment: This is exactly my issue. There is *no* stack trace, not even in the command prompt because it works fine when started from there. The method that writes the rows to a file just randomly stops, at different points of one specific loop depending on how many log message I am printing (again, making me think time is a factor). No loop iterator out of bounds, no array value `null`in that loop...

Comment: When program stops, take thread dump and look if there's deadlock or if thread(s), which should be in Runnable state, is not for some reason (blocked, waiting, timed_waiting) or absent altogether.

Comment: By the way, have a look at your operating system file associations and predetermined programs to execute them.  Are you sure that you are using the same java version both in command line and double-clicking it?

Comment: This might be it. I noticed something else: Trying to do the thread dump in jVisualVM only works from command line. Otherwise the tab for "Threads" doesn't even appear nor does it allow me to do a GC dump in the "Monitor" tab. I'll report back right away.

Comment: I have checked this out and found that both the command line and double-click from desktop use Java SE 1.7.0_21... issue with thread dump also still exists.

Comment: @Jorge_B Could you post your comment as an answer? I deleted all older Java versions as well as the non-64bit ones and now it works perfectly fine. My code works and VisualVM allows me to do thread/ heap dumps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem had to see with the java versions installed in OP's computer.  They checked the file extensions and the programs associated to each one in order to see if it was the same java version as executed from Eclipse and the command line.

Once they cleaned older java versions the jar started to work by double-clicking it :)

Answer (score 0):

Cause I do not have enough points (need 50 to directly answer your question), I need to ask this way:
If you double click a JAR you won't see a console which is often the problem because you can't see stack traces. They get just written to "nowhere". Maybe you get an NPE ore something else.
Try to attach an Exceptionhandler like this `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(UncaughtExceptionHandler)` and let this handler write down a message to a file or such...
Just an idea.

Comment: There is a separate logger in the application to which exceptions and log messages always get printed in all other cases. The output there is precisely the same as what would be printed to the command line as far as I can tell. No hint there..